# file run in browser but failed in Cron Job

Tags: php, xml, cron

I have created a script which read my feed and process it.

I am loading my feed as per blow code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'http://www.xyz.com/feed' );
```

My file works well in Browser, but when I have set up the cron job for this file,
I have got error in email which is as below :

```
Failed to Load External entity
```

Comment: Try running it on the command line with the command used in the cron job.

Comment: How can I do that in local environment?

Comment: that makes it difficult to diagnose then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check PHP settings for CLI and CGI/Apace
For example in debian there in:
/etc/php5/

Answer (score 0):

The command for my cron jobs look something like this when run from local server: /ramdisk/bin/php5 -q /home/king/public_html/crondailyemail.php >/dev/null 2>&1

I'm trying to figure out how to get contents of another server within my cron job, but its not working (probably a security issue preventing it)

Comment: Does this answer the OP's question?